# Why trash folder named as .Trash-1000?

Tags: 12.04

I'm just curious to know why  > Trash folder set to hide ?

> what's the matter with "-1000" in the trash name and what its indicating ?

Comment: Have you had an external drive connected to the system?

Comment: No I  had one drive .

Comment: Not even a USB drive?  What size is that trash folder?

Comment: I've seen that folder  in my usb  . so I want to know that why its set to hidden and what's that 1000 indicates .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If you have had an external hard drive connected to the system
>   sometimes. the trash folder would be named .Trash-1000.  The 1000 is
>   the owner's UID and it is located in the root directory of the
>   partition (hidden). You can empty that folder using the command rm.

<sup>Source: [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org) (specific post unknown)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

It is indicating the user id of the user who owns the trash. And the default, first created user has user id of 1000

It is set to hide, for not cluttering your file browser view. you can see that folder with `CTRL+H` in nautilus