# What is the location of the Trash folder (recycle bin) on Ubuntu?

Tags: filesystem, trash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where is the .Trash folder?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/102099/where-is-the-trash-folder)

Where do I find the trash folder location in my file system?

I am logging in as a non-root user; have searched in my home directory with the `-a` switch with the `ls` command but couldn't find anything related to trash; though I could see some hidden files and directories.

On the other hand on the GUI, there is a folder called Trash which has all the files deleted.  Where can I find this folder on the file system?

Comment: Related questions:  [Where is the trash folder?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/102099/where-is-the-trash-folder), and [Why is the trash folder named as .Trash-1000?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/153415/why-trash-folder-named-as-trash-1000)